# Tkinter, How to save a reference to my Toplevel window that is called from a button

Tags: python, callback, tkinter, widget

I have a top level fully function widget that i would like to open on a button press,

I would like to keep a reference to this instance so that i can read variables from it

I have been thinking about using mixin classes or something similar but if there is a simpler method i would like to try that first. (fairly new to programming)

I have tried the two options below

This one results in this lovely error:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'variables'

```
class addSettings():
    self.pidwind=lambda:Gui_pidSelector(gui_base.configBase(root)# Top Level Reference
    ap_button_cfg= dict(cfg_gui, **{'command':self.pidwind})# opens the Window
```

Other methods i have tried give me the toplevel window opening before the buttonpress.

How can i achieve a reference to this window?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense, because the obvious answer is `$my_window = Toplevel(...)`. Why does that not work for you? Can you give us a very small, fully functioning app that illustrates your problem? Give it a single button that creates a window, so we can see how you are creating it.

Comment: I just thought there might be a way to do it without a function call

Comment: Avoiding a function call is counter-productive. Every button _should_ call a function. It makes your code easier to maintain. Trying to cram a bunch of code into a lambda serves no purpose but to make your code harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i thought there must have been a easy away to achieve this,
i came up with a solution.

```
widget_references={}

def winReferencer(key_name,widget,parent ):
    global widget_references

if key_name not in widget_references.keys(): 
        widget_references[key_name]=widget(parent)

but=Button(text='hi mate', command=lambda:winReferencer('my_window',Toplevel,root)).pack()
```